# Excel: Move x-axis labels horizontally to the right in between tick marks

Tags: excel, charts

I'm trying to move the axis labels so that they are in between the tick marks, but without moving the chart itself.

The chart looks like this:

[image]

If I simply change the axis position to be 'between tick marks' the data points move as well (**NOT what I want**):

[image]

**I want something like this:**

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Dataset:

| financial year | yield |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-22 | 3 |
| 2022-23 | 4 |
| 2023-24 | 5 |
| 2024-25 | 6 |
| 2025-26 | 7 |
| 2026-27 | 2 |
| 2027-28 | 3 |